# Kubernetes Ingress: nginx, use-regex to match exact URL path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a few pods that I am trying to match URLs for their respective services.

Please note that I **need to use** `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` to solve this and **not** `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`

My ingress config file looks like this. Notice the `/api/tile-server/` does not have any regex pattern

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api/auth/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth
              servicePort: 8000
          - path: /api/data/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: data
              servicePort: 8001
          - path: /api/tile-server/
            backend:
              serviceName: tile-server
              servicePort: 7800
```

- `client` pod is a react app built inside nginx docker image working fine
- `nginx.conf` looks like this (if it's helpful)

```
server {
    # listen on port 80
    listen 80;
    # where the root here
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # what file to server as index
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Javascript and CSS files
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

- `auth` and `data` are Flask API pods working fine
- `tile-server` is also a Flask pod but need not do any pattern matching. I need to match the exact `/api/tile-server/` URL

I have tried the following patterns but failed:

- `/api/tile-server/`
- `/api/tile-server/?(.*)`
- `/api/tile-server(/|$)?(.*)`

I can confirm that the pods/services are running on their proper ports and I am able to access them through node ports but not through load balancer/domain.
What would be the right pattern to exactly match `/api/tile-server/` URL?

Comment: Just tested it and the ingess itself works on my cluster. What nginx ingress are you using? And what are the actual errors you are seeing when trying to access? What does the "fail" mean to you in this context? So far my guess is that tile-server is not working correctly and it has nothing to do with ingress, but I will need more information to confirm this.

Comment: I am using EKS and AWS provided ingress-nginx used here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/. Error is 404 returned from the app (tile-server). Hitting example.com/api/auth brings up the root of auth pod. Hitting example.com/api/tile-server/ does not do the same. Tile server is working as I can access it (pod) through NodePort. Tile server runs at its default port at 0.0.0.0:7800 which is the target port

Comment: "I need to use X to solve this and not X" - what do you mean by that? Do you need to use it or not?

Comment: Have you checked the nginx controller's logs for errors?

Comment: "Tile server is working as I can access it (pod) through NodePort" - are you accessing it directly through a nodeport service pointing directly to the pod or through the nginx ingress but bypassing LB and going straight for the nodeport? Please be specific describing what you do/did.

Comment: NodePort is only for testing purposes. The tile server works when accessed through NodePort, hence the proof of work. Through LB + ingress, it's not working. What could be the reason?

Comment: Does the "/api/tile-server/" path exists in tile-server? If not, this is the reason and you need to use rewrite. If it exists, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The path "/api/tile-server/" does not exist. I wanted to know what should be my configuration to make it work at "/" while keeping "/api/tile-server/" in ingress

Comment: Have you tried rewrite-target?

Comment: It will be applied across ingress and the regex won't work for other routes. Best solution we found was to use another subdomain like tile-server.example.com and add the LB to it. Thanks!

Comment: I think I know enough. I will try to write an answer for you. There are at least two solutions to this and I will try to explain them to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First solution** - create separate ingress object for tile-server with rewrite-target annotation. This will work because ingress rules with the same host are merged together by ingress controller and separate ingress object allow for use of different annotations per object:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tile-ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/tile-server(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: tile-server
              servicePort: 7800
```

**Second solution** - rewrite current ingress to work with rewrite-path. Some regex changes are necessary.

Notice the non-capturing group notation: `(?:<regex>)`. This allows to skip numbering for these groups since I need everything relevant to be in the first group in order for it to work, because `rewrite-target: "/$1"`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /(api/auth(?:/|$).*)
            backend:
              serviceName: auth
              servicePort: 8000
          - path: /(api/data(?:/|$).*)
            backend:
              serviceName: data
              servicePort: 8001
          - path: /api/tile-server(?:/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: tile-server
              servicePort: 7800
```

Here is how the rewrites will work for:

- auth service (same applies to data service)

```
    /api/auth      --->  /api/auth
    /api/auth/     --->  /api/auth/
    /api/auth/xxx  --->  /api/auth/xxx
```

- tile-server service:

```
    /api/tile-server      --->  /
    /api/tile-server/     --->  /
    /api/tile-server/xxx  --->  /xxx
```

- client service

```
    /xxx  --->  /xxx
```

Notice that the following paths will be forwarded to client service (where xxx is any alphanumerical string):

```
    /api/authxxx
    /api/dataxxx
    /api/tile-serverxxx
```

If you want them to be forwaded to other/matching services, add `?` after `(?:/|$)` in path.

Comment: This worked! Another solution would be to use subdomains such as https://tile-server.example.com/ and route the traffic to the same load balancer, i.e, in our case worked for AWS NLB

Answer (score 2):

move from v1beta1 to v1 and use pathType: Exact - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Our kubernetes version is 1.18. v1 is available in 1.19+ only. We have other services that are dependent on version 1.18. Cannot upgrade cluster as of now. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
  name: ingress-staging
  namespace: staging
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: acp-service
            port: 
              number: 80
  
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /service-ecommerce(?:/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ecommerce-service
            port: 
              number: 80
```

Thanks @Matt