# Kubernetes Multiple Path Rewrites

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Alright, various permutations of this question have been asked and I feel terrible asking; I'm throwing the towel in and was curious if anyone could point me in the right direction (or point out where I'm wrong). I went ahead and tried a number of [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/rewrite#examples) from the docs, but to no avail (see below).

I'm trying to route traffic to the appropriate location under Kubernetes using an Ingress controller.

#### Server Setup

I have a server, `myserver.com` and three services running at:

`myserver.com/services/`

`myserver.com/services/service_1/`

`myserver.com/services/service_2/`

Note that I'm not doing anything (purposefully) to `myserver.com/`.

At each of the three locations, there's a webapp running. For example, `myserver.com/services/service_2` needs to load css files at `myserver.com/services/service_2/static/css`, etc...

#### Kubernetes Ingress

To manage the networking, I'm using a Kubernetes Ingress controller, which I've defined below. The CORS annotations aren't *super* relevant, but I've included them to clear up any confusion.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myServices
  namespace: myServices
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '$http_origin'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - myserver.com
  rules:
  - host: myserver.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /services
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /services/service_1(/|$)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-service-1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /services/service_2(/|$)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-service-2
            port:
              number: 80
```

#### Targets

I noticed that one helpful thing to do is give some path examples. From the examples below *it looks like the paths aren't that complicated*. I *think* this is what I'm after. Note that I'd like each service to be able to resolve its css and image files.

```
myserver.com/services -> myserver.com/services
myserver.com/services/xxx/xxx -> myserver.com/services/xxx/xxx
myserver.com/services/service_1 -> myserver.com/services/service_1
myserver.com/services/service_1/xxx/xxx -> myserver.com/services/service_1/xxx/xxx
myserver.com/services/service_2/xxx/xxx -> myserver.com/services/service_2/xxx/xxx
```

#### Attempts

I know that this issue has to do a lot with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` rule and its interaction with the paths I've defined.

I *know* that I don't want `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $1` because that gives a 500 when visiting `myserver.com/services`

I *know* that I don't want `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $1/$2` because when I visit `myserver.com/services/service_1` I actually get part of the content at `myserver.com/services` rendered on the page.

##### SO Attempt 1

I also attempted to replicate the accepted solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703968/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-use-regex-to-match-exact-url-path) question.

In this attempt I set

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"` and one of the service paths to

`- path: /(services/service_1(?:/|$).*)`

When I visit `myserver.com/services/service_1/xyz`, the HTML from `myserver.com/services/service_1` gets rendered.

#### Concluding Thoughts

Something ain't quite right with the path rewrite and paths rules. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was interested in this question so I put together [a complete example configuration](https://github.com/larsks/k3s-nginx-example/tree/main), but I was unable to reproduce the problem. The path rules seem to be working as designed. If you deploy the same example, does it work? If so, can you produce a similar example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @larsks Wow I really appreciate that. I replaced my paths with yours, but when I visit something like `myserver.com/services/service_2/should-404` it redirects me to the index page of `myserver.com/services/service_2` instead of 404ing. I see this behavior across the services.

@Mikola S. I'm using Kubernetes 1.23.1

Comment: Thanks for the information. Larsks's solution looks good - as I tested it, it is redirecting a proper paths to the pods in the `web-service-2` - could you please check logs of the pods in the `web-service-2` (`kubectl logs {pod-name}`) and check which path is redirected directly to the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you reported in your most recent comment is resolved by looking at the [rewrite example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) in the nginx-ingress documentation.

The `rewrite-target` annotation configures the ingress such that matching paths will be rewritten to that value. Since you've specified a static value of `/`, anything matching your ingress rules will get rewritten to `/`, which is exactly the behavior you're seeing.

The solution is to capture the portion of the path we care about, and then use that in the `rewrite-target` annotation.  For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myservices
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '$http_origin'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myserver.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /services/service_1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webservice-service1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /services/service_2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webservice-service2
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /services(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: webservice
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here, we've modified the match expression so that they look like:

```
      - path: /services/service_1(/|$)(.*)
```

The second capture group `(.*)` captures everything after the path
portion that matches literally. We then use that capture group (`$2`,
because it's the second group) in the `rewrite-target` annotation:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

With this configuration in place, a request to `/services/service_2`
results in:

```
This is service2.
```

But a request to `/services/service_2/foo/bar` results in:

```
<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
The URL you requested (/foo/bar) was not found.
<hr>
</body></html>
```

And looking at the backend server logs, we see:

```
10.42.0.32 - - [21/Jan/2022:20:33:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 211 "" "curl/7.79.1"
10.42.0.32 - - [21/Jan/2022:20:33:45 +0000] "GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1" 404 311 "" "curl/7.79.1"
```

I've updated [my example repository](https://github.com/larsks/k3s-nginx-example/tree/main) to match this configuration.