# K8s redirect-ingress-URL-issues

Tags: kubernetes, url, redirect

whenever i click on page theres url with wrong and unnecessary symbols at the end of url. i wanna remove that for example [www.hi.com/dictionary/eb/qa/tones/?3459852952093458589730sdfhjsfhw4934gsghsd](http://www.hi.com/dictionary/eb/qa/tones/?3459852952093458589730sdfhjsfhw4934gsghsd)
so it needs to be cut right after tones/
it is running in cluster along with other microservices, i checked all other namespaces they got no issue. they have same configuration.

> apiVersion: extesion/v1beta1 kind: ingress metadata:   name:
> service-ui   namespace: hi theres also annotations:
> fluxcd.io/sync-cheksum: 089980e908fff098f09809e098
> ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
> kubctl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
> kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
> kubernetes.io/tls-acme: 'true'
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true' status:  loadbalancer:  ingress:    -{}

i cound find anything on how to fix this URL How to remove unnecessary symbols at the end of url.

Comment: have you ever checked the annotation of the "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target". Here is the reference link : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Comment: thank you for response! yes i checked it. but i have other namespaces running in same cluster. so if i go ahead and do some changes in particular this problematic service yaml file, does it gonna affect other services running on same cluster? as i said other namespaces ingresses have no problem and running good

Comment: yes, I think so. but you should carry about incoming URL and make necessary changes which are shown in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703968/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-use-regex-to-match-exact-url-path

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply, this problem is solved now